# Can blender render on multiple graphics cards?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a PC which has 2 CPU's in the mainboard, 40 GB RAM and 3 Graphics Cards. Can Blender render for example one frame on all gpus at the same time?
And generally: is it possible to render on cpu and gpu at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Blender's Cycles can use multiple CPUs and GPUs for rendering. You can use both CPU and GPU devices at the same time as well.